# Find in Linux combined with a search to return a particular line

Tags: linux, sed, awk, find

I'm trying to return a particular line from files found from this search:

```
find . -name "database.php"
```

Each of these files contains a database name, next to a php variable like `$dname=`

I've been trying to use -exec to execute a grep search on this file with no success

```
 -exec "grep {\}\ dbname"
```

Can anyone provide me with some understanding of how to accomplish this task?

I'm running CentOS 5, and there are about 100 database.php files stored in subdirectories on my server.

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the arguments to `grep` inverted, and you need them as separate arguments:

```
find . -name "database.php" -exec grep '$dbname' /dev/null {} +
```

The presence of `/dev/null` ensures that the file name(s) that match are listed as well as the lines that match.

Comment: wow, jonathan leffler... ur like a celebrity, top 10 SO users by rep. How did you get so much rep?

Comment: Only #35 on the all-time list (just on the first page).  You get there by answering a lot of questions over quite a long period of time.

Comment: oh so that's how you do it :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this will do it. Not sure if you need to make any adjustments for CentOS.

```
find . -name "database.php" -exec grep dbname {} \;
```

Comment: Or use `+` in place of `;` so that multiple files can be handled with a single `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to habitually avoid find because I've never learned how to use it properly, so the way I'd accomplish your task would be:

```
grep dbname **/database.php
```

Edit: This command won't be viable in all cases because it can potentially generate a very long argument list, whereas find executes its command on found files one by one like xargs. And, as I noted in my comment, it's possibly not very portable. But it's damn short ;)

Comment: It's not actually grep, it's the shell doing filename expansion on ** to recursively match all files in the current directory. zsh has supported this syntax for years, but bash has only had it [since version 4](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option), or a bit over a year. Apparently it's off by default, but on my distro (Arch) it must be set to on, because I tested it in my bash before posting and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out using xargs

```
find . -name "database.php" -print | xargs grep \'database\'\=\> > list_of_databases
```

Feel free to post a better way if you find one (or what some rep for a good answer)